# should I manually add jquery? jquery is not defined in fresh install of wordpress in localhost

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I just installed wordpress 5.6 in my localhost but wordpress is not adding jquery there

I viewed the page-source there is no jquery added in head or before body tag closed

why wordpress is not adding jquery automatically ?

I made a basic theme that depends on jquery as wordpress is not adding jquery, so my theme is not working perfectly.

should I need to manually add jquery? (in my themes function.php)

OR

how can I make my theme to require wordpress to add jquery?

I have another wordpress installed in different directory in localhost. I installed that aroun 3 months ago. in that there all works fine. but in this new install there is no jquery

I tried to figure out the problem. but I didn't find any clue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery will only be added if required by theme.  If you are trying to add a script that needs jQuery, then you can use wp_enqueue_script() function. In dependencies, you need to add jQuery.  Please visit below link for working examples;
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/

You can also enqueue jquery by adding following code:
wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

Comment: I made a basic theme how can I make it to require jquery?

Comment: That's a whole different question, and comments aren't the place for it. Please revise your post to ask that or delete this one and start fresh.